# Centos 7 AD authentication DataProvider is Offline

Tags: centos, sssd

I have configured my Linux machine to use AD authentication. Sometimes few nodes are unable to login.

The  `/var/log/sssd/sssd_nss.log` log file reports the message below:

```
Thu Sep 13 13:31:39 2018) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Thu Sep 13 13:31:39 2018) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
(Thu Sep 13 13:31:39 2018) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline](Thu Sep 13 13:31:39 2018) [sssd[nss]] [sss_dp_get_reply] (0x0010): The Data Provider returned an error [org.freedesktop.sssd.Error.DataProvider.Offline]
```

Rebooting the `sssd` service resolved this issue? What is causing this problem? How can I resolve it?

Comment: I'm seeing this as well and it's a new behaviour as of 7.5, the same config worked on 7.4

Comment: I see this on 7.4, in *pam_sss.log* with `[sssd] debug_level = 3`. I am considering just restarting sssd every night, or monitoring for this string and then restarting sssd.

Comment: @bgStack15 I also thinking of adding nightly restart. it will be good, if we can find the root cause.

Comment: Are the machines joined to the domain, e.g. via realmd?  What are the contents of /etc/sssd/sssd.conf & /etc/krb5.conf?